# Bass alternative tuning picture

Tags: bass-guitar, alternative-tunings

I am a bass player and I use alternative tuning - DGCF to be more specific. I was searching for some nice picture of a fretboard with this tuning but found none (I could, of course, make myself one, but if there already is something like that, it would be great).

I am looking for something like [this](http://www.davidmotto.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/the-bass-fretboard21.jpg) but in DGCF. Thanks for any links - if there is nothing like that, I will, perhaps, post my version of that picture when I make it :-)

Comment: Having taught bass(and gtr) for many years, I've never found a use for this sort of diagram. It's useful, maybe, to have a reference to the 'white notes' i.e. the naturals; then the sharps and flats will be in between.But I can't see how it helps, once you know the open notes, everything else should be referenced to them on the instrument itself.

Comment: Agreed with Tim here - this tuning is simple: all strings are down a M2 from original tuning, therefore, if you're familiar with the layout of a bass in standard tuning, the transposition is simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't made the picture, but looking at your picture, you have DGCF at the 10th fret, and E♭A♭D♭G♭ at the 11th fret, and all the notes repeat at the 12th fret.  So just take the letters from the 10th and 11th frets, copy them down at the bottom, move the fret markers around to match your instrument, and you've got your DGCF fretboard.